# Bash for Windows doesn't see environment variables

Tags: windows, bash, react-native

I'm trying to setup my React-Native application under Bash for Windows. Everything was going fine so far but when I tried to launch `react-native run-android`, I got an error `ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.`. I checked PATH variable that bash sees by executing `env|grep PATH` and it's definitely not my Windows variable.

Is there a way to make Bash for Windows get environment variables from Windows? I believed that's a default behavior as tutorials (like [this one](https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-on-windows-90d85a72ae65#.rmw9rb4dt)) mention nothing about it.

Comment: I don't know, but this probably depends on which of the many Windows distributions of Bash you're talking about.  You should probably clarify that.

Comment: I just installed Bash for Windows that is currently available in Windows

Comment: Looks like the formal name is "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows".  FWIW, I can confirm that this isn't a problem with your particular computer, mine behaves the same way as you describe.  (Perhaps the Windows Insider build behaved differently to the release version?)